# Python pandas: select 2nd smallest value in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example DataFrame like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,2,2,3,3,], 'date':array(['2000-01-01','2002-01-01','2010-01-01','2003-01-01','2004-01-01','2008-01-01'],dtype='datetime64[D]')})
```

I am trying to get the 2nd earliest day in each ID group. So I wrote the following funciton:

```
def f(x):
    if len(x)==1:
        return x[0]
    else:
        x.sort()
        return x[1]
```

And then I wrote:

```
df.groupby('ID').date.apply(lambda x:f(x))
```

The result is an error.

Could you find a way to make this work?

Comment: use nsmallest, added in 0.14.1: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7356

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This requires 0.14.1. And will be quite efficient, especially if you have large groups (as this doesn't require fully sorting them).

```
In [32]: df.groupby('ID')['date'].nsmallest(2)
Out[32]: 
ID   
1   0   2000-01-01
2   1   2002-01-01
    3   2003-01-01
3   4   2004-01-01
    5   2008-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [33]: df.groupby('ID')['date'].nsmallest(2).groupby(level='ID').last()
Out[33]: 
ID
1    2000-01-01
2    2003-01-01
3    2008-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: you can pass a list as well

Comment: how can I keep other columns in a dataframe if they exist?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the indexing [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) - in general pandas defaults to indexing by label, rather than location - that's why you get a `KeyError`.

In your particular case you could use `.iloc` for location based indexing.

```
In [266]: def f(x):
     ...:     if len(x)==1:
     ...:         return x.iloc[0]
     ...:     else:
     ...:         x.sort()
     ...:         return x.iloc[1]
     ...:     

In [267]: df.groupby('ID').date.apply(f)
Out[267]: 
ID
1    2000-01-01
2    2003-01-01
3    2008-01-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Specific part of the docs about `.iloc` vs. `.loc` [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix).

Answer (score 1):

You may not want to return the first and only value as the second value as in the accepted answer (i.e., `2000-01-01` is not the second value, but the only value).  If this is the case, you can rank each group and be able to select the first, second, third, etc. smallest value more generically:

```
df['rank'] = df.sort_values('date').groupby('ID').cumcount()+1
```

For the second smallest value:

```
df[df['rank'] == 2]
```

this returns

```
ID  date        rank
2   2003-01-01  2
3   2008-01-01  2
```