# Pandas get second minimum value from datetime column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a DateTime column, I can get minimum value by using

```
df['Date'].min()
```

How can I get the second, third... smallest values

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943902/python-pandas-select-2nd-smallest-value-in-groupby

Answer (score 4):

Use `nlargest` or `nsmallest`

For second largest,

```
series.nlargest(2).iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dates are in datetime first:

```
df['Sampled_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Sampled_Date'])
```

Then drop the duplicates, take the nsmallest(2), and take the last value of that:

```
df['Sampled_Date'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(2).iloc[-1]
```

Comment: Hey, I had a full working answer your Fast.com question, but the question got deleted. If you reopen the question I can post it? Or contact me from the email in my info, whichever you prefer

Comment: I've created a question and wrote a detailed answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131422/5298150