# How to get internet speed results from Fast.com

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to regularly check my internet speed and reset my router if it drops a certain threshold, which seems to fix the crappy connection my ISP "provides".

Although there might be easier ways to go on about this, I figured I should get the results from Fast.com, which gives me the results I need, like download speed, upload speed, and ping times to a server close to me.

Looking for any pointers.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT 2020-11-03:** I've fixed the code, and it works again thanks to [Carlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5364599/carlos-manrique-enguita).

---

The page is JS-driven, and there's no easy way to get the results by simply scraping the HTML off the page, so `requests` and `bs4` alone won't help you.
You need to run a full modern browser to let the test run, and wait however long it needs and then get the results.

## Setup

Ok, let's use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for this, which can control Chrome, Firefox, Safari, basically any browser under the sun.

Install the package by running:

```
pip install selenium
```

We also need to install a driver to control our browser, you can find it [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers) (In fact read the page about installation completely, it has everything you need to get it running). Then we need to place that executable in our `PATH`. Easiest way is to just put it under `c:\Windows` on Windows or `/usr/bin` on Linux. But there's tons of documentation on SO and in the internet, so learn the proper way to do this correctly, you'll need it.

With that out of the way, we also need [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/), which is the defacto HTML parser (on that note, we can keep using selenium and browser, but I'm used to using bs4 for this job). Install it using

```
pip install bs4
```

## Running the test

Now to get the results, we need to run the browser, go to https://fast.com, let the test finish, then get the HTML for the results, then extract the info we need.

### How do we know when the test is finished?

Well, we could just wait, like 30s until everything finishes. But what if it finishes early? Or not finish at all? Then we'd have waited for no reason. There's a better way.

When the test finishes, the spinner turns green. And if we watch the DOM from the Developer Console, we see that it gets a `succeeded` class.

[image: download results are in]

But if we expand the results, we see the upload results are not in yet, when that happens, the page is updated once more and we reach at this state:

[image: upload results are in]

### Waits

Selenium has an [*explicit wait*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) feature that lets you wait until something happens on the page. We'll use it to check and wait until some element with `.succeeded` class is present on the page. If you just need the download speeds, simply wait for spinner to get `.succeeded` class, if you also need the uploads results, you need to wait for that instead. For this job we can use this helper function:

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def wait_until_present(driver: Chrome, selector: str, timeout: int = 5):
    condition = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(condition)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        raise LookupError(f'{selector} is not present after {timeout}s') from e
```

## Extracting the results

Once the results are in, we get the HTML for the parent element that contains both upload and download results.

```py
# this is the parent element that contains both download and upload results
results_selector = '.speed-controls-container'
results_el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(results_selector)
results_html = results_el.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

Then we feed the HTML to BeautifulSoup and extract the values.

## Code

Here's the code in its entirety:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def get_chrome() -> Chrome:
    # https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager
    opts = ChromeOptions()
    # opts.headless = True
    driver = Chrome(options=opts)
    yield driver
    driver.close()


def wait_until_present(driver: Chrome, selector: str, timeout: int = 5):
    condition = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(condition)
    except TimeoutException as e:
        raise LookupError(f'{selector} is not present after {timeout}s') from e


def extract_speed_info(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> dict:
    dl_speed = soup.select_one('#speed-value').text
    dl_unit = soup.select_one('#speed-units').text
    upload_speed = soup.select_one('#upload-value').text
    upload_unit = soup.select_one('#upload-units').text

    return {
        'upload': f'{upload_speed} {upload_unit}',
        'download': f'{dl_speed} {dl_unit}'
    }


def run_speed_test() -> dict:
    with get_chrome() as driver:
        driver.get('https://fast.com')

        # wait at most 60s until upload results come in
        download_done_selector = '#speed-value.succeeded'
        upload_done_selector = '#upload-value.succeeded'
        wait_until_present(driver, upload_done_selector, timeout=60)

        # this is the parent element that contains both download and upload results
        results_selector = '.speed-container'
        results_el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(results_selector)
        results_html = results_el.get_attribute('outerHTML')

    # we're finished with chrome, let it close (by exiting with block)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results_html, 'html.parser')
    info = extract_speed_info(soup)
    return info


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        results = run_speed_test()
        print('Speed results:', results)
    except LookupError as e:
        print('Cannot get speed results')
        print(e)
        exit(1)
```

output:

```
{'upload': '320 Kbps', 'download': '3.4 Mbps'}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line client for fast.com written in golang: https://github.com/ddo/fast/releases

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by [abdusco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5298150/abdusco) was very helpful. Anyway, now in 2020 it doesn't work. To load the upload result it is necessary to click on the "show more information" button after the download test is completed.
To fix that, just add another wait_visble after loading the page and click the button.

This is the code that must be modified from abdusco's answer:

```
    upload_done_selector = '#upload-value.succeeded'
    more_info_selector = "show-more-details-link"
    wait_visible(driver, "#"+more_info_selector, timeout=60)
    driver.find_element_by_id(more_info_selector).click()
    wait_visible(driver, upload_done_selector, timeout=60)
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. You don't really need to click anything. I've changed the wait condition from visible to user to present in page, and it works without any major changes

Answer (score 0):

Currently (March, 2024) the syntax of the "driver.find_element_by_css_selector(results_selector)" has been changed and the "results_el" assignment should now be "results_el = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, results_selector)

With that change, the program worked for me.