# Pandas: get column name of (row-wise) n-smallest value of selected columns

Tags: pandas

Consider the following sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
n = 200

df = pd.DataFrame({'v1': np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
                   'v2': np.random.randint(10, 90, n),
                   'v3': np.random.randint(10, 90, n),
                   'another_v': np.random.randint(10, 45, n)})
```

In this data, I would like to add a new column `minval` with the smallest value in `['v1', 'v2', 'v3']` and another one `mincol` with the column indicator of the column containing this minimal value.

I do this using the following code, which works fine.

```
df['minval'] = df[['v1', 'v2', 'v3']].min(axis='columns') # minimum value
df['mincol'] = df[['v1', 'v2', 'v3']].idxmin(axis = 'columns').str[1:]
```

However, how can I get the same for the *second*-smallest value?

S. below for expected output of a sample

```
    v1  v2  v3  another_v   2minval     2mincol
0   66  55  30  37          55          2
1   92  68  22  44          68          2
2   98  69  36  38          69          2
3   17  33  71  15          33          2
4   83  35  49  23          49          3
5   57  37  62  38          57          1
6   86  67  89  37          86          1
7   97  13  49  19          49          3
8   96  88  18  13          88          2
9   47  69  36  33          47          1
```

(Similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130799/pandas-get-second-minimum-value-from-datetime-column) suggesting `nlargest` etc. only provide solutions for within-column comparisons.)

Comment: it would be helpful if you shared a minimal dataframe with expected output. You could even add `np.random.seed(2)` to ensure the randomisation is constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for improve performance not loop apply solution in `numpy`:

```
np.random.seed(200)
n = 200

df = pd.DataFrame({'v1': np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
                   'v2': np.random.randint(10, 90, n),
                   'v3': np.random.randint(10, 90, n),
                   'another_v': np.random.randint(10, 45, n)})

df['minval'] = df[['v1', 'v2', 'v3']].min(axis='columns') # minimum value
df['mincol'] = df[['v1', 'v2', 'v3']].idxmin(axis = 'columns').str[1:]
print (df[:10])
   v1  v2  v3  another_v  minval mincol
0  26  31  65         35      26      1
1  16  52  54         12      16      1
2  68  14  22         10      14      2
3  42  73  67         26      42      1
4  55  87  21         36      21      3
5  76  40  16         26      16      3
6  79  37  31         19      31      3
7  89  46  78         13      46      2
8  14  64  29         17      14      1
9  91  85  73         31      73      3
```

Use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for positions of sorted values and then reorder columns names by this positions to `a` array with select last previous `'column'`:

```
v = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']

arr = np.argsort(-df[v].to_numpy())
a = np.array(v)[arr]
print (a[:10])
[['v3' 'v2' 'v1']
 ['v3' 'v2' 'v1']
 ['v1' 'v3' 'v2']
 ['v2' 'v3' 'v1']
 ['v2' 'v1' 'v3']
 ['v1' 'v2' 'v3']
 ['v1' 'v2' 'v3']
 ['v1' 'v3' 'v2']
 ['v2' 'v3' 'v1']
 ['v1' 'v2' 'v3']]
```

Also you can reorder values - so last previous `'column'` are second min values:

```
b = df[v].to_numpy()[np.arange(len(arr))[:,None], arr]
print (b[:10])
[[65 31 26]
 [54 52 16]
 [68 22 14]
 [73 67 42]
 [87 55 21]
 [76 40 16]
 [79 37 31]
 [89 78 46]
 [64 29 14]
 [91 85 73]]
```

`Series` is used for possible pass `str[1:]`

```
df['second_mincol'] = pd.Series(a[:, -2], index=df.index).str[1:]
df['second_minval'] = b[:, -2]

print (df)
     v1  v2  v3  another_v  minval mincol second_mincol  second_minval
0    26  31  65         35      26      1             2             31
1    16  52  54         12      16      1             2             52
2    68  14  22         10      14      2             3             22
3    42  73  67         26      42      1             3             67
4    55  87  21         36      21      3             1             55
..   ..  ..  ..        ...     ...    ...           ...            ...
195  63  81  39         12      39      3             1             63
196  85  38  31         39      31      3             2             38
197  63  17  21         40      17      2             3             21
198  24  20  31         10      20      2             1             24
199  95  55  16         26      16      3             2             55

[200 rows x 8 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `apply` method (with axis=1 to look across the row), sort the values in descending order then return the second item (indexed to 1):

```
df['second_minval'] = df[["v1", "v2", "v3"]].apply(
    lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False)[1], axis=1
)
```